# Using find method of the list collection

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections

I have a web application in which I use `List` collection. I'd like to replace this snippet by another more efficient.

```
List<Project> liste = notre_admin.Get_Project_List();
Project p = new Project();
foreach (Project pi in liste)
{
    if (pi.Id_project == id_project) {p = pi; break;}
}
```

I'd like to replace these lines of code by one line in which i use `find` method of the `List`.

How can I change the snippet ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`Linq`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx) to resolve it. First, include the namespace:

```
using System.Linq;
```

After, try to find the first element using a lambda expression in [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/bb340482.aspx) extension method:

```
var item = liste.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id_project == id_project);
if (item != null) 
{
   // use the object found
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LINQ` for that (as *Felipe Oriani* suggested), or `List<T>.Find` method (which won't require additional `include` statements):

```
List<Project> liste = notre_admin.Get_Project_List();
Project p = liste.Find(x => x.Id_project == id_project);
```